How to send multiple records per person from Data Cloud to Marketing Cloud in 1 segment?
I am working with Salesforce Data Cloud and need to send data to Marketing Cloud where one person can have multiple records (e.g., multiple cart ids). When I create a segment in Data Cloud and activate it in Marketing Cloud, the Subscriber Key becomes the Primary Key in the Data Extension, which limits me to one record per person.
In Data Extensions, I can set two Primary Keys, for example, Subscriber Key and CartId, which allows multiple records for one subscriber. However, I haven’t found a way to achieve this when sending data from Data Cloud to Marketing Cloud.
My questions are:

Is there a workaround to allow multiple records per person in Marketing Cloud when sending data from Data Cloud?
Is it possible to configure more than one Primary Key (like Subscriber Key and another field such as CartId or EnrollmentId) when activating a segment from Data Cloud?
Are there best practices for handling multiple records per person in scenarios like this?

Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Were you able to figure this out ?

When you activate to Marketing Cloud you can choose related attributes, and it would be at that time you select the multiple Cart Ids. The Related attributes would then be sent within a JSON payload in a text field that you'd have to parse out with the BuildRowsetFromJSON ampscript. There's limitations on related attributes
Related Attributes: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_activate_data_related_attributes.htm&type=5
Limits: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_limits_and_guidelines.htm&type=5

Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to go over the limitation of max 5 values in the JSON for a one customer? Or I need to create another segment with the same related attributes to get another 5 json objects (next 5 values in the json)

@teddy23 Data Cloud has some guardrails to reduce general processing and this is one. Related attributes is a very high recursive row read activity, but I know of many instances where limits can be adjusted behind the scenes. Create a case to find out if they'll increase it for you.

Thank you for your response. Do you perhaps see any other option for sending more than 5 related attributes in SFMC, apart from simply creating 2 or more segments with 5 values each by creating rules in each segment that would ensure different data goes into each segment, so they don’t all contain the same 5 values?

@teddy23 that's a tough one. Data Cloud's not currently set up for bulk egress.
